# Как убрать букву E при делении в C#

Tags: c#, консоль, деление

Вот мой код:

```
using System.IO;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters;

int kills;
int helps;
int deaths;
int points;

string path_kills = @"F:\Кирилл\C#\CS GO\k.txt";
string path_helps = @"F:\Кирилл\C#\CS GO\h.txt";
string path_deaths = @"F:\Кирилл\C#\CS GO\d.txt";
string path_points = @"F:\Кирилл\C#\CS GO\p.txt";

Console.Write("Kills: ");
int new_kills = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Helps: ");
int new_helps = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.Write("Deaths: ");
int new_deaths = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int new_points = new_kills * 2 + new_helps * 1 - new_deaths * 2;

using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path_kills)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
    await fstream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string textFromFile = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    kills = Convert.ToInt32(textFromFile);
}

using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path_helps)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
    await fstream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string textFromFile = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    helps = Convert.ToInt32(textFromFile);
}

using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path_deaths)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
    await fstream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string textFromFile = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    deaths = Convert.ToInt32(textFromFile);
}
using (FileStream fstream = File.OpenRead(path_points)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fstream.Length];
    await fstream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    string textFromFile = Encoding.Default.GetString(buffer);
    points = Convert.ToInt32(textFromFile);
}

kills += new_kills;
helps+= new_helps;
deaths += new_deaths;
points += new_points; 

if (points < 0) {
    points = 0;
}

using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path_kills, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(kills));
    await fstream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path_helps, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(helps));
    await fstream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path_deaths, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(deaths));
    await fstream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

using (FileStream fstream = new FileStream(path_points, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) {
    byte[] buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(points));
    await fstream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

Console.WriteLine($"\nkills: {kills} (+{new_kills}, {kills - new_kills})");
Console.WriteLine($"helps: {helps} (+{new_helps}, {helps - new_helps})");
Console.WriteLine($"deaths: {deaths} (+{new_deaths}, {deaths - new_deaths})");

if (new_points < 0) {
    Console.WriteLine($"points: {points} ({new_points}, {points - new_points})");
}
else {
    Console.WriteLine($"points: {points} (+{new_points}, {points - new_points})");
}

Console.WriteLine((float)kills / deaths /*Вот здесь получается число с буквой E*/);
```

Пример:

Kills: 2;
Deaths: 5;

Получаю: 1,4296815E-05

Comment: Измените формат вывода, если такой вызывает затруднения при прочтении

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring

Comment: 2 / 5 это 0.4, а не то что вы показали.